# Align element to the right of multiline text without a margin

Tags: html, css

This is a little hard to explain. I have an `inline-block` element, that has multiple lines. As soon as it breaks, there is some white-space on the right which still pushes another element far right.

What I want to achieve is, that the next element is next to the `inline-block` [like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7kBx.png).

This is my current solution, which does not provide the expected outcome:

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!-- this one has not the expected outcome -->
<div>
  <span>Someone has a very loooong wooooooooooord.</span>
  <em>&gt;</em>
</div>

<!-- this one on the other hand does -->
<div>
  <span>This one works fine.</span>
  <em>&gt;</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `inline-block` element?

Comment: Updated my question - had done some changes and forgot to undo them

Comment: Essentially, **you can't** - that's not the way the linebox model works.

Comment: I see... thanks for your answer! @Paulie_D or rather your duplicate. I didn't know what to search for :D